# How to change the Android EditText to select the cursor style, select the style similar to iPhone

Tags: android

I need to Android edittex select the style, modify as similar to the iPhone style, what need to be done[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW6QI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I highly discourage you from copying the iPhone style, However, if you have not got any alternatives then look into creating a custom edittext specifically looking at the setSelection method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, customers want this style, so it is only as a way to imitate